# Common Template Library

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to create a view that only houses reusable HTML blocks that can be used by other views. Wanted to know if something like this is possible:

**In views.home.common.scala.html:**

```
@component1 = {
  some common html
}
@component2 = {
  some other stuff
}
```

**In views.home.sample.scala.html:**

```
@(user:User)
import home._

@component1
@common.component2
```

Haven't had any luck thus far and I don't see anything similar in the samples but the idea is covered in the [Template common use cases](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/wiki/ScalaTemplateUseCases).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having this same issue. What I did was defining for each common block a file and then import the package that contains all those files.

For example:

**In views.common.component1.scala.html:**

```
<div>
    Common component 1
</div>
```

**In views.common.component2.scala.html:**

```
<div>
    Common component 2
</div>
```

**In views.main.scala.html:**

```
@(content: Html)

@import common._

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        @component1()
        @component2()
    </body>
</html>
```